# perl file test operators and "$_"

Tags: perl

I'm going through O'Reilly's "Intermediate Perl". `-s` is used as so:

```
print map { "    $_\n" } grep { -s < 1000 } @ARGV;
```

which gives this warning:

> Warning: Use of "-s" without parentheses is ambiguous Unterminated <>
>   operator

Though, when I put parentheses around `-s` it works like a charm. 
Not sure if this is perl version related or a mistype by authors.

> Perl version: v5.18.2 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

What is causing this issue and what I can do to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

`<` can be the start of a term as the `readline`/`glob` shortcut.

```
print "[$_]\n" for < a b c >;
```

`<` can be the start of an infix operator as the numeric less-than operator.

```
print "foo\n" if $x < 3;
```

`-s` can legally be followed by both, so Perl has to guess which one you wanted when it sees the `<`. Using any of the following instead of `-s` solves the issue since none of them can be followed by a term:

- `-s($_)`
- `-s()`
- `(-s)`

Comment: I would recommend `-s ($_)` as it makes the intent considerably more clear.